# Closing a Userform with Unload Me doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to close an Excel userform using VBA when a user has clicked a submit button and operations have been carried out.

How can I close a Userform from itself?

I have tried this but it returns a 361 error.

```
Unload Me
```

Comment: Where do you call `Unload Me` from?

Comment: Need more information. DoCmd is an MS-Access Command and not MS-Excel Command. Are you trying to close an Excel userform from Access?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I thought so when I was doing research - just it was suggested on a number of forums.

Comment: @Cutter The end of a btnSubmit_Click handler

Comment: Can you explain a little more in detail on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: After the user submits data in a form (clicks the submit button) I want to form to close

Comment: If you are doing this from with Excel Userform then "Unload Me" is the right way to do it. There must be some other reason. Can you share the complete code for the btnSubmit_Click?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8325/discussion-between-kian-mayne-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Please do not edit an answer in to the question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As specified by the top answer, I used the following in the code behind the button control.

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

In doing so, it will not attempt to unload a control, but rather will unload the user form where the button control resides. The "Me" keyword refers to the user form object even when called from a control on the user form. If you are getting errors with this technique, there are a couple of possible reasons.

1. You could be entering the code in the wrong place (such as a
   separate module)
2. You might be using an older version of Office. I'm using Office 2013. I've noticed that VBA changes over time.

From my experience, the use of the the DoCmd.... method is more specific to the macro features in MS Access, but not commonly used in Excel VBA.

Under normal (out of the box) conditions, the code above should work just fine.

Comment: Recommend to read the article [UserForm1.Show?](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) explaining why it's *not* the best idea to use `Unload Me` (as well as the UserForm's default instance :-).

Answer (score 11):

Without seeing your full code, this is impossible to answer with any certainty. The error usually occurs when you are trying to unload a control rather than the form.

Make sure that you don't have the "me" in brackets.

Also if you can post the full code for the userform it would help massively.

Comment: Apologies, the full code was posted [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2784564#2784564)

I'll update the question to include it

Comment: But also I did post that the code `Unload Me` returned the 361 error

Comment: Hi Kian, That isn't the full code for the userform, it is the code for the submit button - you have class level declarations etc... Can you post the full code for the userform - including the Unload me that doesn't work?

Comment: No class level declarations or anything; but it's suddenly started working so I have no idea what the problem was.

Comment: hmmm  mdlRegex looks suspiciously like a class to me... Glad it's working though :) - btw your regexp check doesn't work for emails

Comment: Well it definitely didn't cause any errors, and when you said *class **level** declarations* I assumed you meant variables that had been declared at class level, not just class definitions

Comment: It isn't declared in the sub, so must be declared at the top of the form class?

Comment: No, it's just in the excel project

Comment: Ah right ok, its best not to declare global variables unless you really need to, in my experience they can cause more problems than they cause and usually aren't neccessary :)

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I had Me in brackets and it never worked.  I read this and took it out and it works. Why is this?  I thought functions/procedures could be entered with or without the brackets, so why the difference with this?

Answer (score 4):

Unload Me only works when its called from userform self. If you want to close a form from another module code (or userform), you need to use the Unload function + userformtoclose name.

I hope its helps

Comment: It is called from the userform.

Comment: Can you shed some light as to why it's not working? Because I already knew that Unload Me only works when it's called from the userform you want to close.

Comment: Kian, what about Unload Userform1, for example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491001/closing-userform-excel-vba/9499359#comment12114726_9557119

Answer (score -1):

It should also be noted that if you have buttons grouped together on your user form that it can link it to a different button in the group despite the one you intended being clicked.