# escape Userform (having controls) with ESC key

Tags: vba, ms-word, keyboard-events, userform

I have a UserForm with two buttons and a number of check boxes:
[image: Userform]

How do I configure the form so that I can `Cancel`/ `Escape` it with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key?

Comment: Or you can do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240677/close-userform-with-escape-button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure there is a "Cancel" button on the UserForm, and set the `Cancel` property of that button to `True`.  In the code for that button, execute `Unload Me`, `Me.Hide`, or however you want to exit the userform.  E.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938039/2877364).